# Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::json() in src\addons\EWR\Rio\Api\YouTube.php at line 80

Tags: php

Am trying fix XF2 plugin and not work :/

```
try
    {
        $client = \XF::app()->http()->client();
        $response = $client->get(self::$base.'channels', [
            'query' => [
                'part' => 'snippet,brandingSettings',
                'id' => $matches['sval1'],
                    'key' => $service->service_apikey
            ],
        ]);
        $json = $response->json();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
```

Please help me with Youtube API on XF2 Thanks :)

Comment: If you have composer, you can install guzzle like this:
composer require guzzlehttp/psr7